# Show Data from Json Result

Tags: php, json, api

I have a curl request, I'm trying to get to display the  'name' from the JSON result in PHP but can't find anything about it all requires Jquery and AJAX.

```
<?php
    $url="https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/alphamonkey95?api_key="myapikey";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $result=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
?>

<html>
    <body>
    <div>
    <p>Display name here</p>
I'm guessing the echo['name'] Well tried that but it didnt work. 
    </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Results in JSON which is displayed on the page. I only want to display certain results.

```
array(6) { ["id"]=> int(85169216) ["accountId"]=> int(226919821) ["name"]=> string(13) "AlphaMonkey95" ["profileIconId"]=> int(3233) ["revisionDate"]=> int(1522708809000) ["summonerLevel"]=> int(73) }
```

Comment: decode it like what you have already `$data = json_decode($result, true); ?>` and just wrap it with php tag if its mixed along the markup, `<p><?php echo $data['name']; ?></p>` like so

Comment: Thank you.So much how would I hide the remaining results from the page? So it only shows the ones I echo in PHP.

Comment: just `echo` the ones you need to, just use the `var_dump` to examine the structure, after you know whats inside, just remove it and use `echo` accordingly

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
$json = json_decode($result, TRUE); //return an array
var_dump ($json['name']);
```

I prefer objects myself:

```
$json = json_decode($result);//return an object
var_dump($json->name);
```

When you convert arrays back and forth JS doesn't have associative arrays, so it will convert non-numeric arrays to objects.

Comment: Thanks for your help too! :)